# How much controller per area is a lot

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few areas in my ASP MVC project. One area has near 15 controllers and about 6-7 actions per controller. Is it a lot and would it be smarter to make area per controller?

Ok I need to provide a little more informations:
I am in the middle of the project I designed database and domain model library. Now I have asp mvc project with all controlelr in root controller folder. And I now trying to switch to areas and because I am new in all asp mvc world and areas I don't know did I choose right areas and controllers. Here is the short list if what I got so far:

```
Area: Authentication {AccountController, RegisterController, ForgotPasswordController}

Area: School {AboutController, ArticleController, EventController, GroupController, VoteController, QuestionController, GalleryController, TeachersController, CoursesController, NewsController, StatisticController, InformationBoardController etc.}

Area: SchoolLife {StatusFeedController, ProfileController, EventController, GroupController, VeoteController, QuestionsController, StatusBoxController, ImagesController, VideosController etc.}

Area: Admin {...}
```

Comment: Depends. Give us a list of your areas, controllers and actions; then we can say if the divisions follow the core tenets of MVC and REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Area per controller wouldn't make much sense. Your question is a little subjective and difficult to answer in an objective manner but let me share what I do (which of course doesn't mean that it is correct, it's just how I like working). Personally I very rarely use areas, not to say never. I prefer a RESTful organization of my application, where I define resources and for each resource I have a controller defining the standard eight operations on this resource:

[image]

Depending on the size of the application and the number of resources I am dealing with I could have lots of controllers.

Comment: @1110 may not have a resource-based application. Also, if you only route by resource type (like `/MyResourceType/1/Delete`), then having separate controllers for each resource seems redundant. One controller could rule them all!

Comment: @bzlm, yes indeed he might not have a resource-based application. And the *one controller rule them all* rule scares me like hell :-) I have seen that during code reviews. It was a total nightmare.

Comment: I updated my question with some information of my project structure. Can you check out please?

Comment: @1110, your organization seems fine. Just `School` and `SchoolLife` probably could be merged in the same area if they encapsulate the same entity. Also don't be afraid of multiplying your controllers. That's a good thing.

Comment: They are completely different thing that's why I put them in separate areas. But you give me some valuable information. Thanks